# rem working for fontsize, but not working for height and width

Tags: ionic2, responsive

I am using ionic2, having an issue on responsive layout for all mobile device. I am using rem to set the layout, however rem working for font-size, but not working for height and width. below is code snippet and the screenshots:

```
<div class="test">test</div>

.test{
            width: 6rem;
            height:4rem;
            line-height: 2rem;
            font-size: 1.5rem;
            background: #06c;
            color: white;
        }
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    html {font-size: 50% }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 321px)  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    html {font-size: 62.5% }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 376px)  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
    html {font-size: 75% }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 415px)  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
    html { font-size: 100% }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37uRF.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cehma.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working after i changed the smallest font size of Chrome. default is 12px, so the 50% and 62.5% not working. thanks any way

billy